# Reading a schema: left vs right

Tags: uart, pins

I am trying to understand how to read the schematic for my [Creator CI20](http://elinux.org/MIPS_Creator_CI20). My board looks like this:

[image]

Looking at the documentation the dedicated UART header has 4 pins:

[image]

Which are documented here:

- http://www.elinux.org/CI20_Hardware#Dedicated_UART_header

Is there a way for me to tell appart which pin is designated as '1' or which one is designated as '4' ?

Comment: Look at the board.  The connectors all have a small triangle pointed at pin 1.

Comment: Very nice ! Is there a name for this convention ?

Comment: Don't know of a special name for it.  Most connectors will have some kind of marking.  Either in the silk screening or on the connector itself.  Of course, you have trust in the guy doing the layout got pin 1 right, and that whoever did the circuit nunbered his pins the same as the connector when it is marked.

Comment: You're asking about schematics, but have not posted any. What you think _schematic_ means in this context?

Comment: Removed incorrect tag, sorry about that.

Comment: ...and the title?

Comment: In addition to other markings mentioned, for through-hole parts, the PCB pad for pin 1 is sometimes square vs round for other pads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all is just as easy as following the links:

[your link](http://elinux.org/MIPS_Creator_CI20) -> [schematic link](http://elinux.org/CI20_Hardware/Documentation#Schematic) and from here

-> [circuit diagram](http://mipscreator.imgtec.com/CI20/hardware/board/CI20_V1.0_schematic.PDF)

-> [board with all pinouts](http://mipscreator.imgtec.com/CI20/hardware/board/CI20_V1.0_layout_with%20part%20number.pdf)

It is an open source project, and you should find a lot of info for it, as well as dedicated forum/discussion board where you can ask deep dive questions about it.